# I want to have VBA code for family tree. I believe its quite simple but i am unable to do it, Any help will be highly appreciated

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2021

I have following data in Excel

[image]

I need above data in below format. Kindly let me know VBA code for this.

[image]

As elzibethII has child Charles & charles has child then charles will be in the next line after elzibeth & same for the remaining.

I have try different VBA codes with different scenarios but unfortunately its not quite successful

The code is given below

```
Sub final()

Dim i, j, a, lrr, b, c, d, e, f As Long
Dim nm, nm1, nm2 As String
Dim rng As Range

lrr = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 1
'finding max number
  If lrr > 1 Then
   
   Set rng = Sheet5.Range("A1:A" & lrr)
   a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
  
  End If
b = 2
c = 2

For i = 2 To lrr
   nm = Sheet5.Cells(b, 13).Value      
     For c = i + 1 To lrr      
       If Sheet5.Cells(c, 12).Value = nm Then    
         Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 16).Value = Sheet5.Cells(c, 11).Value
         Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 17).Value = Sheet5.Cells(c, 12).Value
         Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 18).Value = Sheet5.Cells(c, 13).Value
         Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 19).Value = Sheet5.Cells(c, 14).Value
         'a = a + 1
         c = c + 1
       
         e = Sheet5.Cells(c, 16).Value
        ' nm2 = Sheet5.Cells(c, 18).Value
         While e <= a         
          For j = c To lrr
             nm2 = Sheet5.Cells(c, 18).Value             
             If Sheet5.Cells(j, 12).Value = nm2 Then
              'e = Sheet5.Cells(c, 16).Value
              Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 16).Value = Sheet5.Cells(j, 11).Value
              Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 17).Value = Sheet5.Cells(j, 12).Value
              Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 18).Value = Sheet5.Cells(j, 13).Value
              Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 19).Value = Sheet5.Cells(j, 14).Value
              'a = a + 1
               c = c + 1
               e = Sheet5.Cells(c, 16).Value
                 If e = 5 Then
                                    
                   nm2 = Sheet5.Cells(c, 17).Value
                   f = j
                   For f = j + 1 To lrr
                    
                    If Sheet5.Cells(f, 12).Value = nm2 Then
             
                    Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 16).Value = Sheet5.Cells(f, 11).Value
                    Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 17).Value = Sheet5.Cells(f, 12).Value
                    Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 18).Value = Sheet5.Cells(f, 13).Value
                    Sheet5.Cells(c + 1, 19).Value = Sheet5.Cells(f, 14).Value
                    'a = a + 1
                     c = c + 1
                    End If                   
                   Next
                 End If                                
             End If 
          Next
         e = e + 1
         Wend        
     End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

i am getting till 1st part and code is not going for the other parts as given below.

[image]

Comment: This is not simple as it's likely a recursive function is the best route to tracking the depth of the hierarchical path, which is a more advanced programming technique. Instead of a question on stackoverflow, you likely need a developer.

Comment: @JNevill
Thanks for your feedback but it can be done with excel VBA. Initially, the data is much more complex & i manage to bring it to above level. I believe it can be done by aligning level with parent but i am stuck at it.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I am very well aware that it can be done in VBA via a recursive function. Again, there isn't going to be canned code for this and the logic will need to be written by someone with the skillset to write it. If you have written some code already to attempt this, then please share it and we can help you with the specific part you are stuck on. It's unlikely anyone is going to sit down and write this for you though. The downvotes and closure are a reflection of that "Write this for me" request. There are sites online where you can hire a developer for a one-off job like this.

Comment: @JNevill
Kindly check the post again as i have give the code & the results

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0):

- Use nested Dict object to store data
- Use a recursive function to retrieve parent-child chain

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim arrRes(), iR As Long
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, objDic As Object
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, aRow(1 To 4)
    Dim sParent As String, sChild As String, sFirst As String
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 4)
    ' populate header
    iR = 1
    For j = 1 To 4
        arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(1, j)
    Next
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) = 1 Then ' top node of each family
            If Len(sFirst) > 0 Then
                Call GetChild(objDic, "", sFirst)
                ' reset Dict
                objDic.RemoveAll
            End If
            sFirst = arrData(i, 3)
        End If
        sParent = arrData(i, 2): sChild = arrData(i, 3)
        If Not objDic.exists(sParent) Then
            Set objDic(sParent) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        End If
        ' get data row
        For j = 1 To 4
            aRow(j) = arrData(i, j)
        Next
        ' add to Dict
        objDic(sParent)(sChild) = aRow()
    Next i
    GetChild objDic, "", sFirst
    ' write output to sheet (starts from cell F1), modify as needed
    With ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Resize(iR, 4)
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = arrRes
    End With
End Sub

' recursive function to get the child node
Sub GetChild(oDic, sPar, sChi)
    Dim vKey, aRow, j As Long
    aRow = oDic(sPar)(sChi)
    iR = iR + 1
    ' populate output array
    For j = 1 To 4
        arrRes(iR, j) = aRow(j)
    Next
    '    Debug.Print Join(aRow, "|")
    If oDic.exists(sChi) Then
        For Each vKey In oDic(sChi).keys
            'get next level
            Call GetChild(oDic, sChi, vKey)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sir i have no words to thank you sir. 
Great sir this code is working & i wast stuck with very basic VBA.
Once again Than you sir